# How to Unpack-Pack MTK NVRAM.bin?

Tags: android, pack

I am developing a MTK IMEI repair program in Android.

In order to be successful I must edit MP0B_001 file located in NVRAM.bin Or NVRAM.img and then pack it again.

This image showing NVRAM.bin contents (I don't know how they pack/unpack it)

[image: IMAGE: NVRAM.bin contents]

I searched a lot in Stack Overflow and XDA Developer and GitHub, but I found programs to unpack boot.img + logo.img + system.bin+Kernel+Recovery Images **not NVRAM.bin**

I tested all this tools:

[image: Image: Tested tools]

I uploaded Lenovo-A319_nvram.bin for you to test:

[Download NVRAM](http://www.mediafire.com/file/zua5v9cuqyzw2pp/NVRAM+Lenovo+A319.rar)

Comment: Security warning: if that binary blob contains executable code, **readers are strongly advised not to run it** unless their run environment can be thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify nvram.bin you can modify this in your rooted device
this is folder in /data/nvram
after modify you can backup by mtk driod tools:
https://androidmtk.com/backup-and-restore-imei-nvram
mtk droid gives to you a nvram.bin file!

for replace imei file you can replace your file with /data/nvram/md/nvram/NVD_IMEI/MP0B_001 in rooted device! not forget your file name shoud be same MP0B_001

good like!